# start a new activity causes a stackoverflowError

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-activity, stack-overflow

I am trying to create a in-app feedback email. I have the function below:

```
public void sendEmail(){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There are no email clients installed.",        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

However, when I called this method, which will start a new activity, I will got the StackoverflowError likes:

```
09-16 13:44:31.923: E/AndroidRuntime(1079): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 13:44:31.923: E/AndroidRuntime(1079): Process: com.example.demo, PID: 1079
09-16 13:44:31.923: E/AndroidRuntime(1079): java.lang.StackOverflowError
09-16 13:44:31.923: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.example.demo.database.MySQLiteHelper.close(MySQLiteHelper.java:59)
09-16 13:44:31.923: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.example.demo.database.MySQLiteHelper.close(MySQLiteHelper.java:59)
09-16 13:44:31.923: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.example.demo.database.MySQLiteHelper.close(MySQLiteHelper.java:59)
09-16 13:44:31.923: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.example.demo.database.MySQLiteHelper.close(MySQLiteHelper.java:59)
```

Do you guys have any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats happening at or around this line here?

"at com.example.demo.database.MySQLiteHelper.close(MySQLiteHelper.java:59)"

Comment: For some reason calling close on your database is calling close on your database is calling close on your database....

Comment: in that line, I only called this.close();

Comment: I call close database in main activity onPause() function. Does it cause the problem?

Comment: I think the MySQLiteHelper.close() calling himself instead of calling the close on the SqLiteOpenHelper instance

Comment: So as MySQLiteHelper.open() ?? Don't we have to call it on the activity?